# not stuffing string values in js

Tags: javascript

I want to randomize user input string using `sort()` function..
but it's not working properly. Can anybody help me solving this problem?

```js
function getAndSetVal() {
  var txt1 = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  document.getElementById('txt2').value = txt1;
}

// get value
function getVal() {
  var txt = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  alert(txt);
  txt1.sort(function() {
    return .5 - Math.random();
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" onclick="this.value = '' " />
<button onclick="getAndSetVal();">Get Value</button>
<input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt" onclick="this.value = '' " />
```

Comment: The `sort` comparator function takes 2 arguments, the left and the right item.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Doesn't it also need to return `-1`, `0`, or `1`? `0.5 - Math.random()` won't do that.

Comment: then how to add it

Comment: Well you never even call the function,.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  It doesn't need to be `-1,0,+1`,  `<0, =0, >0` will work.

Comment: **Use case explanation is vague and insufficient** (couple of perfectly functional snippets rejected by OP without a clear reason), so voted to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the word, sort, and re-join.

If the random number i.e. 0 -> 1 falls in:

- the first third, return -1
- the last third, return +1
- the middle, return 0

**Edit:** Instead of `Math.random()` (which is predictable), you can implement a seeded random number generator. David Bau's `seedrandom` library is light-weight and easy to integrate into your JavaScript application.

Just drop the script in your `<head>` and instantiate a new random number generator with a seed of the current time in milliseconds.

```js
var random = new Math.seedrandom(new Date().getTime());

function shuffle() {
  document.getElementById('txt2').value = randomSort(document.getElementById('txt').value);
}

function randomSort(value) {
  return value.trim().split(/\s*,\s*/).sort((a, b) => {
    return ((p) => {
      return p < (1/3) ? -1 : p > (2/3) ? +1 : 0;
    })(random()); // Instead of Math.random()
  }).join(', ');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/seedrandom/3.0.5/seedrandom.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" value="Banana, Orange, Apple, Mango" />
<button onclick="shuffle()">Shuffle</button>
<input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt" />
```

Comment: var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.sort(function(){return .5-Math.random();});
document.write(fruits);

Comment: look at above code how its randomize all strings separately but i just want randomize user input string

Comment: @Vicky how are they inputting the values?

Comment: Shuffling with `sort()` is [slow](https://jsperf.com/array-shuffle-mine/1) and inefficient (try *shuffling* `abcdefg`-string several times - it returns original string after couple of iterations). There's a much faster and *way more random* [shuffling method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56749849/11299053). I know, you have taken that from OP, but proceeding this way means encouraging OP to go wrong way.

Comment: ABC, xyz, sunny, funny, pqr ...... like this

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I addressed the random issue.

Comment: @Vicky Just split the words by optional white-space (surrounded) commas, sort with a random number, and join the words back into a string.

Comment: thanks for help ... problem solved

Comment: @Vicky I just updated my response, since you did not originally say you were splitting on words.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl : *'...I addressed the random issue'* and it is still slow and now unnecessarily overcomplicated

Answer (score 0):

String are arrays in some sense but not really, so you have to create an array to use the sort function, try like this:

```js
    function shuffle(){
        document.getElementById('txt2').value = getVal();
    }

    function getVal()
    {
        const txt = document.getElementById('txt').value;
        return txt
            .split(",")
            .map(word => word.trim())
            .sort((a, b) => Math.random() > .5 ? 1 : -1)
            .join(", ");
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" value="orange, avocato, banana, fruit" />
<button onclick="shuffle()">Shuffle</button>
<input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt" />
```

And the sort function pass two parameter and expect return the values 1, -1 or 0.

1 when the first parameter should came first

-1 when the second parameter should came first

0 when doesn't matter the order between both parameters

Comment: @Vicky see if this works for you

Comment: not working bro..

Comment: see this code how it's work.. but instead of providing strings in program i want to provide strings from user input

Comment: var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.sort(function(){return .5-Math.random();});
document.write(fruits);

Comment: Got it, try this new version.

Comment: ohh bro Thanks working perfectly now...